# Increasing the allocationSize generates a NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to insert into my (Oracle) database a collection of `Mother` objects which have a list of `Child` objects. All the ids of those objects are generated using a sequence:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MOTHER")
public class Mother implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_MOTHER")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_MOTHER", allocationSize=100)  //Error?!?
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "mother", 
               orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> children;    
}
```

I quite simply insert several thousand of `Mother` instances thanks to the `persist` method:

```
    for (Mother mother : mothersToInsert) {
        entityManager.persist(mother);
    }
```

In my model, f I don't set any `allocationSize` (default is 50 according to the documentation) or set it to a value lesser than 50 then everything runs fine.

Yet if I try setting it to 100 or more then I keep having a `NonUniqueObjectException`:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: 
    a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with 
    the session
```

A "*solution*" could be to change the `Cascade`(I did not try to change it) but I would like to persist all the children instances when persisting the mother instances (and retrieving them...)

I *might* not need to set the `alocationSize` to a high value, yet how could I increase it in order to increase insertions performance without getting that exception? And how to be sure that even when not setting it an error is not hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

You must set the `allocationSize` of the generator to the same value as "INCREMENT BY" on your sequence. [Read this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing) for more information on sequencing with JPA.